# change url .htaccess php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page name `page.php` and my url as `localhost/mysite/page.php` , now how can i change the url using `.htaccess` file to `localhost/mysite/somethinghere1/somethinghere2/page.php`

It tried using the below code but it doesn't work out.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable Rewriting 
RewriteEngine On 

# Rewrite user URLs 
#   Input:  user/NAME/ 
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME 

RewriteRule ^somethinghere1/somethinghere2/.php? page.php

</IfModule>
```

how can i acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
RewriteRule ^somethinghere1/somethinghere2/([^/\.]+).php/?$ page.php
```

Comment: I have edited the question and i also check your solution but it doesnt work out.

Comment: I got this one, but i need the `localhost/mysite/page.php` url to be changed to `localhost/mysite/something1/something2/page.php` and that what i am looking for.

Comment: @Rafee: so you need redirect localhost/mysite/page.php to localhost/mysite/something1/something2/page.php, you can do that using .htaccess to.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(mysite/)somethinghere1/somethinghere2/(.*\.php)/?$ $1$2 [L,NC]
```

Also make sure this in .htaccess file in your DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page.php /page.php?first=$1&second=$2 [NC]
```

This is the basic code , you can play with it to fit your needs like the following edit :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$3.php?first=$1&second=$2 [NC]
```

So x/y/z would be z.php?first=x&second=y