# php - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Can't seem to get all the style and javascripts..

URL: http://localhost/filename/home/

Redirected: http://localhost/filename/index.php

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /filename/
RewriteRule ^(.*)home/$ index.php [NC]
```

Also tried adding this to the header file: `<base href="/filename/">`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `.htaccess` file the same directory, where you want to put up these and you check this out [change url .htacess php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968421/change-url-htacess-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use rewrite condition before re-write rule, like -

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(\.js|\.css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)home/$ index.php [NC]
```

If js and css are into any directory, You can also use re-write condition like bellow -

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(script|styles)
RewriteRule ^(.*)home/$ index.php [NC]
```